# Webpack export modules like lodash

Tags: webpack

Lodash exports modules like that:
`var chunk = require('lodash/array/chunk');`

I would like to create a library that exports modules in the same way. so with another project I can import only the modules that I want:

`var module1 = require('my-library/moduel1');
var module2  = require('my-library/module2');
var moduele3 = require('my-library/module3');`

or with amd
`define(['my-library/moduel1', 'my-library/moduel2',''my-library/moduel3'], function ...)`

So I believe that my configuration for the library are not correct, they are:

```
var path = require('path'),     
    webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: '#inline-source-map',
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'my-library/module1' : path.resolve(__dirname, './lib/module1/index.js'),
            'my-library/module2' : path.resolve(__dirname, './lib/module2/index.js'),
            'my-library/module3' : path.resolve(__dirname, './lib/module3/index.js'),
        }
    },
    entry: {
        app: './lib/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        library: 'my-library',
        libraryTarget: 'amd',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "my-library.js"
    },
    externals:{
        'lodash': '_'
    },
    plugins: [  
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: "my-library/module1", 
                loader: "exports-loader"
            },
            { 
                test: "my-library/module2", 
                loader: "exports-loader"
            },
            { 
                test: "my-library/module3", 
                loader: "exports-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Am I using the exports-loader not correclty? Also do you know any examples on github?
Thanks

Comment: Is it a public library? Webpack might not be the ideal tool for this purpose. I've used Babel for Node distribution versions myself while leaving bundling (single UMD bundle) for other platforms to Webpack.

Comment: It is public whitin my company.
Not sure which one is the best tool to use.

Comment: What module format are you using for `./lib/module1/index.js` etc.?

Comment: CommonJS so inside `./lib/module1/index.js` there is something like: `module.exports = { obj1 : 'ciao', obj2 : 'hello'}`

Comment: Ok. Maybe it's just easiest to make `package.json` main to point at the current structure then? Tooling should be able to pick that up I think.

Comment: Interesting thanks! But what kind of tools are you thinking of?

Comment: I mean at least Webpack and Browserify should be able to pick that up. It depends on what you are going to use on the consumer side.